# Can different PostgreSQL timestamps be equal?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Sometimes, I see `ORDER BY date, id`. Why is `id` needed?

How can two different times ever be equal?

What is the precision of `timestamp`?

Comment: Two different times will never be equal. But there is nothing that prevents storing two equal values in two different rows (except for a unique index)

Answer (score 1):

You asked about "ORDER BY date, id." but then mention timestamp. A field named date might be of type timestamp or date like 'YYYY/MM/DD' in which case order by id would be relevant

Comment: So, `id` is not needed if `date` is a `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1):

Since timestamps are discrete values there can be multiple timestamps with the same value regardless of the precision. The bigger the precision the least likely is a collision. An untie criteria is necessary if that is relevant.